# How to create a nameserver?

Tags: dns, nameserver

I am hosting my own website at home. I have bought a domain .com and now I have to enter two nameservers.

How can I create a nameserver that would point to my IP?

I have optical fiber, so I can't have a fixed IP, is there any way for that nameserver to update my IP always it's changed

Comment: Have you looked in to one of the many Dynamic DNS providers that will supply you with the nameserver that will follow your IP (none of the ones I know of will do it for free if you are providing your own domain name instead of using one of their premade ones). EDIT: And if you wanted to host your own you would need a static IP to host it, however if you had a static IP to host it you would not need your own nameserver.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily want to run your own DNS server, I'm guessing. But rather, you just want to point your hostname to your dynamically moving IP address. This can be achieved in many ways. DynDns has a service to do this for just $25/year. http://dyn.com/remote-access/

The mechanics are that you have some type of agent (an "update client") that will report your machine IP to Dyn, and they will keep your DNS record pointing to your machine.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer!! I have already paid for that website. Now I am configuring my dns. There's something I don't understand. It gives me to choose for service type between: - Host with IP address - WebHop Redirect (URL forwarding service) -  Offline Hostname. Which one should I choose ?